# Tweepy Search API Writing to File Error

Tags: search, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Noob python user:

I've created file that extracts 10 tweets based on the api.search (not streaming api). I get a screen results, but cannot figure how to parse the output to save to csv. My error is TypeError: expected a character buffer object.

I have tried using .join(str(x) and get other errors.

My code is

```
import tweepy
import time
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Cursor

#Consumer keys and access tokens, used for Twitter OAuth 
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

# The OAuth process that uses keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

# Creates instance to execute requests to Twitter API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

MarSec = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='maritime security').items(10)

for tweet in MarSec:
    print " "
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.lang

saveFile = open('MarSec.csv', 'a')
saveFile.write(tweet)
saveFile.write('\n')
saveFile.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've gotten my Streaming API to work, but am having difficulty with this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tweet` is not a string or a character buffer. It's an object. Replace your line with `saveFile.write(tweet.text)` and you'll be good to go.

```
saveFile = open('MarSec.csv', 'a')
for tweet in MarSec:
    print " "
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.lang
    saveFile.write("%s %s %s\n"%(tweet.created_at, tweet.lang, tweet.text))

saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and it's successful for only one tweet (the last one), but I want to return the full data set of the 3 items: text, the created_at and the language in my output file. Thanks and still stumped.

Comment: `tweet` exists inside the loop only, move the writing there, and you should be finished.

Comment: Thanks so much. Moved into the loop and it works now. I'm running into a new error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 159: ordinal not in range(128) that I'll research tomorrow.

Comment: That's a separate problem :) Ask again if you still need help!

Comment: Thanks got it to work using the csv writer and encode(utf-8) from the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976599/tweepy-search-api-writing-to-file-error by @user3325317 

I would upvote now but will when I get enough points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd put up another version for those who might want to save all 
the attributes of a `tweepy.models.Status` object, if you're not yet sure which attributes of each tweet you want to save to file.

```
import json

search_results = []
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_text).items(5000):
    search_results.append(status._json)

with open('search_results.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(search_results, f)
```

The first block will store the search results into a list of dictionaries, and the second block will output all the tweets into a json file.
Please beware, this might use up a lot of memory if the size of your search results is very big.

Comment: how much is the approximate size of a  status._json object?

Answer (score 0):

This is Twitter's classic error code when something is wrong while sending a wrong image.

Try to find images you are trying  to upload and check the format of the images.

The only thing I did was erase the images that MY media player of Windows can´t read and that's all! the script run perfectly.